# If process is running do this, else do that

Tags: java, linux, process

I have a small app with only 1 button. What I want it to do is check if a process is running when button is pressed. It it is, do x, if it isn't do y.

This is my humble code so far. I know it only includes the button, and the click and nothing else. I am really blank on this one.

```
public class toggle {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Display myDisplay = new Display();
      Shell myShell = new Shell(myDisplay);
      myShell.setText("uTorrent Toggle");
      myShell.setBounds(120, 120, 220, 120);
      myShell.setLayout(new FillLayout());
      final Button Start = new Button(myShell, SWT.PUSH);
      Start.setText("Start uTorrent");
      Start.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
         public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent event) {
             Start.setText("Kill uTorrent");
             try {
                Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/bin/bash -c \"utorrent start\"");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
         }
      });
      myShell.open();
      while (!myShell.isDisposed()) {
         if (!myDisplay.readAndDispatch()) myDisplay.sleep();
      }
      myDisplay.dispose();
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To check if a process is running you could use the output of "ps -efw" or with different arguments depending on your needs.